# Add Phonon::SeekSlider in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, phonon

I’m trying to add a `Phonon::SeekSlider` in Qt Creator but can only add it to my form in code.

```
seekSlider = new Phonon::SeekSlider(this);
seekSlider->setMediaObject(mediaObject);
ui->setupUi(this);
seekSlider->show();
```

How can I add the SeekSilder in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 0):

There's a section in widget selector for Phonon objects (at least in Qt Creator 2.3 with Qt 4.7). It contains the `SeekSlider`, `VideoPlayer`, `VideoWidget` and `VolumeSlider` widgets.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have /usr/lib/qt4/plugins/designer/libphononwidgets.so. If not install package: libphonon4-designer